# T/F: Matrix is invertible when considered as a matrix with entries in R but it is not invertible when considered as a matrix with entries in Zmod11.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am working on a problem, but I am not completely sure about my answer it:

[image: the problem]

I have chosen False, since when I calculate the determinant over $\mathbb R$, it does not equal $0$  (as $12-3 = 9$), which implies the matrix is invertible. When I calculate the determinant mod $11$, I get the same determinant ($12 - 3 \equiv 1 - 3 \equiv -2 \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$), which implies the matrix is invertible.

Is my conclusion correct?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your conclusion is correct

Comment: You can even construct the inverse using the adjoint method as in real case. Only difference is when you divide by determinant, you divide in $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$ which is to say that you multiply by the inverse of the determinant in this field.